# Java Questions

Tags: java

I'm TAing for an introductory course in Java for freshmen. So, far we've learnt most of Java except the OOPS part. Like we can do methods, loops, control stuctures, arrays, strings, recursion etc..
Since this is their first programming course, they are not aware of fancy datastructures yet.

I have dont most of the regular programs like factorial, fibonacci, primes etc..

I'm looking for some interesting problems in the space without using complex datastructures. Any ideas would be super helpful.

thanks, Vinbot

Answer (score 2):

[Project Euler](http://www.projecteuler.net/) has some problems that you can solve without additional data structures, and all the problems have the nice property of being mathematically interesting. Not all the problems will work for your course, but I bet you can find enough that do, especially among the first few.